# Symfony - one record lazy loads out of many

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have an entity

```
#[ORM\Table(name: 'settings_slp_plan')]
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: 'ASG\Bundle\MiningSettingsBundle\Repositories\SlpPlanRepository')]
class SlpPlan
{
    #[ORM\Column(name: 'id', type: 'bigint', nullable: false)]
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: 'IDENTITY')]
    private ?int $id=null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: 'ASG\Bundle\MiningSettingsBundle\Entity\Operation']
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: 'operation_id', referencedColumnName: 'id')]
    private Operation $operation;

    #[ORM\Column(name: 'description', type: 'string', length: 255, nullable: false)]
    private ?string $description = null;

    #[ORM\Column(name: 'start_date', type: 'datetime', nullable: false)]
    private ?\DateTime $startDate;
    #[ORM\Column(name: 'end_date', type: 'datetime', nullable: false)]
    private ?\DateTime $endDate;
    }
```

When I call $this->slpPlanRepository->findAll(), there are 6 records, 5 of them return as SlpPlan entities, index 2 returns as a proxy. Why is this happening?

[image: query_results]

Comment: It look like it is already inside your entityManager, look at __isInitialized__ 
It is set to true for the record which is proxy.

Comment: Thanks, totally missed that. Does this mean there's somewhere in the code where the class is initialized or pulled of the DB first, but somehow still in memory when this findAll() is called?

Comment: You could try an `entityManager->clear()` before your findall just to be sure entity manager is empty